# What does 睨んでの指示 mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, words

Context: some students have been ordered by the student council to go to a meeting to talk about a competition with another school, but one of them refuses to go. Then the teacher replies.

> Student: なぜ我々が奴らに従わねばならんのだ。話があるのなら向こうが出向けば良いだろう。
>
> Teacher: まぁそう言うなって。今年の勝敗はお前達にかかってると**睨んでの指示**だろうからな。

My attempt: "Come on, don't say that. This year's victory depends on you, so I think they ordered you to go just to keep an eye on you".

I think that the sense is that the student council doesnt'have bad intentions, they just want to be sure they will win the competition. Is this the correct meaning? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [睨]{にら}む means:

> にらむ【睨む】
>   ❸ 見当をつける。めぼしをつける。「犯人はあいつに違いないとにらむ」「にらんだ通りの結末になる」
>   (明鏡国語辞典)

I think it means "to guess", "to foresee", "to estimate", "to judge", or "to suspect" depending on context.

> 「今年の勝敗はお前達にかかってる」と睨んでの指示だろう

"I think they ordered you to go, foreseeing/judging that this year's victory depends on you."